# Append big image after the small image is dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a  "draggable only" block where  I have some images and another "sortable only" block where I can drop the items from the "draggable only".

What I want to do is when I drag the image into "sortable only" to append the larger version of the dragged image  which is hosted on my server.

I think this can be relatively easy to do if there is a way to check when the item is dragged into the sortable list and then append the new image.

This is the actual JS :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".sortableList").sortable({
    revert: true,
    /*update: function (event, ui) {
        // Some code to prevent duplicates
    }*/
});
$(".draggable").draggable({
    connectToSortable: '.sortableList',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid'
});
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Y562/1/) with what I currently have:

(Hover over the "Headers" and there you should drag an image into "HOVER OVER HEADERS AND DROP IMAGES HERE" block)

I've looked trhrough the plugin API but I can't find a way to track when the item was dragged into the sortable area ?

Any suggesions on how can I do this ?

Comment: Are you looking for when the item is dragged over the sortable area or when the item is actually dropped into the sortable area?

Comment: when it's actually dropped into the sortable area

Comment: Alright, then the receive function in my answer should do the trick. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: I've tried something, please check my comment on your answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're shooting for, a receive function on your sortable list should work.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6Y562/2/)**

```
 $(".sortableList").sortable({
     receive: function (event, ui) {
         alert('It works');
     }
 });
```

[The documentation says](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive):

> This event is triggered when an item from a connected sortable list
>   has been dropped into another list. The latter is the event target.

But apparently it will also fire when using a connected draggable.

Comment: I'm thinking to use jQuery append() method to put there a bigger image but the problems is that it displays both of them, the smaller one and the bigger one inserted through append() method. Any suggestions on how can I make this work ?

Comment: Another thing is that I will have more images items so how can I check what item is dragged and based on that to append the bigger image version ?

Comment: @agis honestly I'm a little stumped on that one. This is as close as I could get using `replaceWith()` http://jsfiddle.net/6Y562/3/

Comment: This seems a little bit closer for what I want to achieve, however do you have any idea how can I stop the dragged elements from replacing and replace just the dragged and dropped elements ?

Comment: @agis That's where I got stuck, sorry I couldn't be more helpful. It may be worth asking a new question and linking back to this one for context.

Comment: Yes, I think I will ask a new question, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking the jQuery UI API and found this:

```
$( "#sortable li" ).droppable({
    drop: function( ) {
        //do the magic
    }
});
```